# Getting Android location from GCMIntentService

Tags: android, locationmanager, google-cloud-messaging

I want to get the location of a user in Android when he receives a GCM notification.
so in my `GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService` I'm doing this :

```
   @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message. Extras: " + intent.getExtras());
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        syncLocations(context);

    }
```

In syncLocation I'm doing things correctly to get the location

```
public void syncLocations(Context context)
    {

        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    mLocationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,
                    mLocationListener);

    }
    public LocationListener mLocationListener   = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(
                String provider,
                int status,
                Bundle extras)
        {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(
                String provider)
        {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(
                String provider)
        {}

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(
                Location location)
        {
//HANDLE LOCATION
        }
    };
```

syncLocation works correctly if it is called from inside the app.

But when i call it from the notification onMessage(), it enters the method, but onLocationChanged is never called. I suspect it has something to do with the context.

Can anyone please give me any info why it isn't working ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone please give me any info why it isn't working ?

Because `GCMIntentService` is an `IntentService` and goes away (via `stopSelf()`) shortly after `onMessage()` returns. You cannot reliably do things like register listeners for location changes from an `IntentService`.

Also, bear in mind that the device may be asleep when the GCM message comes in. `GCMIntentService` will keep the device awake long enough to call `onMessage()`, but once `onMessage()` returns, the device can fall back asleep.

Comment: Thanks, now it all makes sense. So the best solution would be to create a service that will be called from GCM ?

Comment: @DanyY: Yes, you will need a regular `Service`, one which you control the lifetime of, that can get the location fix, do whatever you wanted to do with it, and *then* shut itself down.